# two elements of same class in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium web driver using the language "Java" and want to access two elements of same `classname`. Actually, both the elements are error messages which are coming in small popup having the same class.  But the problem is that every time it only picks the first element of the class which is coming. Please suggest which method I should use to get both the elements.

Also, I need to compare both the messages with the string that I have added. Here is the code I have tried:

```
public class mysignup {
public static WebDriver d;
    public static void main(String []args)throws Exception{
        d = new FirefoxDriver();
        d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        d.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("qwertyuiokjhgfdsazxcvbnmkloiuytr");
        d.findElement(By.name("firstname")).click();
        d.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys("singh");
        d.findElement(By.name("email_id")).sendKeys("abcgmail.com");
        d.findElement(By.name("firstname")).click();
        d.findElement(By.name("email_id")).click();

       String bodyText = d.findElement(By.cssSelector(".popover-content")).getText();
```

Comment: Please use Xpath OR cssselector if elements have same class.

Comment: Providing corresponding HTML would us to help u bettr !

Answer (score 0):

While findElement returns you a single WebElement, [findElement**s**](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) will return all elements that match given conditions.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your valuable comments. I have tried below and it also worked :):)                                                   d.findElements(By.className("popover-content")).get(0).getText(). It gave me text from index value.

Answer (score 0):

In such a scenario I would suggest using `findElements` method. It will return you a list of all elements if found or an empty list. So you can try out with:

```
List<WebElement> lstEle = d.findElements(By.cssSelector(".popover-content"));
List<String> strLst = new ArrayList<String>();// list to contain all texts in each element
lst.forEach(new Consumer<WebElement>() { // foreach element add text to strLst
    @Override
    public void accept(WebElement t) {
        strLst.add(t.getText());
    }
});
```